# Cannot cast to same type of different jars (Apache FOP, URL ClassLoader)

Tags: java, apache, casting, classloader, apache-fop

Using the [DirectoryBasedParentLastURLClassLoader](https://github.com/paoloantinori/custom-classloader/blob/master/v2/src/main/java/paolo/test/custom_classloader/DirectoryBasedParentLastURLClassLoader.java) 
I want to use a specific Fop-Framework instead of the one, which is already loaded into the classpath.
By trying to initialize this specific class via java reflection, I receive this error:

```
org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory cannot be cast to org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory
```

The test-class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;

public class FOPTest {

    private FopFactory fopFactory;

    public FOPTest() {
        try {
            DirectoryBasedParentLastURLClassLoader classLoader = new DirectoryBasedParentLastURLClassLoader(
                    "C:\\path\\To\\FOP\\Jar\\Fop10" );
            Class<FopFactory>classManuallyLoaded = (Class<FopFactory>) classLoader
                    .loadClass("org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory");
            for (Method method : classManuallyLoaded.getMethods()) {
                method.setAccessible(true);
            }
            for(Constructor consr : classManuallyLoaded.getDeclaredConstructors()) {
                consr.setAccessible(true);
            }   
            Method methodToString = classManuallyLoaded.getMethod("newInstance");
            Object res=null;
            methodToString.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                res = methodToString.invoke(classManuallyLoaded.newInstance());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error protected: " + e);
                res = methodToString.invoke (classManuallyLoaded);
            }

            System.out.println("GET CLASS: "  + res.getClass());
            if(res  instanceof FopFactory) {
                System.out.println("Instance of FopFactory");
            }
            this.fopFactory =  (FopFactory) res;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        new FOPTest();
    }

}
```

and the console output

```
Error protected: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class showproject.FOPTest can not access a member of class org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory with modifiers "protected"
GET CLASS: class org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory cannot be cast to org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory
    at showproject.FOPTest.<init>(FOPTest.java:38)
    at showproject.FOPTest.main(FOPTest.java:45)
```

I hope, someone can help me creating the FopFactory based on the class of the DirectoryBased-ClassLoader

Comment: Are you sure that org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory is a public object?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the external DirectoryBased-ClassLoader does not works perfectly. There's not cast-problem by using the java URLClassLoader. Thx